# How to keep a value with react context?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

Here are 3 basic components `searchBar` which refers to the **search bar form**  and, the `searchPage` component which **displays the search results**, and of course, the `app` component which **contains them all**.

**mechanism:**

1. the user submits an input in the **searchBar component**, the
   `handleSubmit` function gets fired, which changes the state of
   `setSearchedProducts` to the input value, by `useContext` **AND**
   getting pushed to the ("/SearchPage") by `history.push()` .

```js
import {useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { LocaleContext } from "../../../LocaleContext";



const SearchBar = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const {setSearchedTerm} = useContext(LocaleContext);

    
    const handleSubmit = (SearchTerm) => {
        setSearchedProducts(SearchTerm)
        history.push("/SearchPage");
    }
    
    
    return (
      <form>
        <input onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e.target.value)}>
        </input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
}

export default SearchBar
```

2. the value gets sent to the **app component** by react context and
   the state gets set to the value while still pushing to the
   ("/searchPage").

```js
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { searchBar, searchPage } from "./components";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import  {LocaleContext} from "./LocaleContext"


const App = () => {

 const [searchedTerm, setSearchedTerm] = useState("");


 const providerValue = useMemo(() => ({searchedTerm, setSearchedTerm}),
 [searchedTerm, setSearchedTerm])



    return (
        <Router>
            <LocaleContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
            
                <searchBar />
                
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/SearchPage">
                        <SearchPage />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>

            </LocaleContext.Provider>
        </Router>

    );
}

export default (App);
```

3. displaying the **searchPage component**, which gets the state value
   by using `useContext`, and with `useEffect`, the `fetchProducts()`
   function gets fired, that fetches a set of **products** based on the
   state value.

```js
import {useState, useEffect, useContext}  from 'react';
import { LocaleContext } from "../../LocaleContext";

const SearchPage = ({}) => {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const {searchedTerm} = useContext(LocaleContext);

  const fetchProducts = (term) => {
      setLoading(true);
      const url = new URL(
          "https://example/products"
      );

      let params = {
          "query": term
      };

      Object.keys(params)
          .forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]));

      let headers = {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
      };

      fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: headers,
      })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
              setProducts(json); 
          });

  }



  useEffect(() => {
      fetchProducts(searchedProducts)
  }, [])


  return (
      {
        products.map(product => (
          <div>
            {product.name}
          </div>
        ))
      }
  )
}

export default SearchPage
```

**Issues:**

- when the router changes to the ("/searchPage") component state value get lost, meaning it returns to **""** value. ?
- lesser problem, if the user sends an empty string (" "), and the **API** needs a value or it will give an error, what is the solution to that?
- is there a way of keeping the value after reloading the page?

```js
import {createContext} from "react";

export const LocaleContext = createContext(null);
```

this is the `localeContext` component if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add `e.preventDefault()` in your `onSubmit` handler. Otherwise you're getting a page reload which causes a state loss.

Comment: that worked, but is there a way of keeping the value after reloading the page?

Comment: yes, you can store the data locally on the client (with localStorage / cookies etc) or on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed "setSearchedProducts" & "setSearchedTerm" should be the same in your code below. This might be your issue!

```js
const SearchBar = () => {
    ...
    const {setSearchedTerm} = useContext(LocaleContext);

    
    const handleSubmit = (SearchTerm) => {
        setSearchedProducts(SearchTerm)
        ...
    }
```